# grpc iOS stream, send only when GRXWriter.state is started?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, stream, grpc

I'm using grpc in iOS with bidirectional streams.

For the stream that I write to, I subclassed `GRXWriter` and I'm writing to it from a background thread.

I want to be as quick as possible. However, I see that `GRXWriter`'s status switches between `started` and `paused`, and I sometimes get an exception when I write to it during the `paused` state. I found that before writing, I have to wait for `GRXWriter.state` to become `started`. Is this really a requirement? Is `GRXWriter` only allowed to write when its state is `started`? It switches very often between `started` and `paused`, and this feels like it may be slowing me down.

Another issue with this state check is that my code looks ugly. Is there any other way that I can use bidirectional streams in a nicer way? In C# grpc, I just get a stream that I write freely to.

**Edit:** I guess the reason I'm asking is this: in my thread that writes to `GRXWriter`, I have a `while` loop that keeps checking whether `state` is `started` and does nothing if it is not. Is there a better way to do this rather than polling the `state`?

Answer (score 4):

The GRXWriter pauses because the gRPC Core only accepts one write operation pending at a time. The next one has to wait until the first one completes. So the GRPCCall instance will block the writer until the previous write is completed, by modifying its state!

In terms of the exception, I am not sure why you are getting the problem. GRXWriter is more like an abstract class and it seems you did your own implementation by inheriting from it. If you really want to do so, it might be helpful to refer to GRXBufferedPipe, which is an internal implementation. In particular, if you want to avoid waiting in a loop for writing, writing again in the setter of GRXWriter's state should be a good option.